# Properties which are constant on conjugacy classes of a group

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Let $\Phi$ be some property which might hold of an element of a group, and say that in every group, $\Phi$ holds for some element $x$ of the group if and only if it holds for all the conjugates $g^{-1}xg$ of $x$.  That is, for every group $G$, $$\forall x\in G.\Phi(x)\text{ if and only if } \forall g\in G. \Phi(g^{-1}xg).$$

For example, the property $\Phi$ of being self-inverse is of this type: if $x^{-1} = x$, then $\left(g^{-1}xg\right)^{-1} = g^{-1}xg$ for every $g$.
Another example is the property of being a central element of the group.

> Is there a name for properties of this type?

Comment: A function which is constant on conjugacy classes is called a *class function*, so I suppose $\Phi$ could be called a *class property* (though I've never seen anyone use that term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that there is a name for this property. There are infinite examples of course. For every natural number $n$ let $\Phi_n(x)$= [the order of $x$ divides $n$]. Another one: let $S$ be a *normal* subset of the group $G$. And $\Phi_S(x) = [x \in S]$. Observe that characters (trace functions of representations) are constant on conjugacy classes. However character might have the same value on *different* conjugacy classes.

Comment: Your belief that there is a name for this property has more probative weight if you are a professional group theorist or a historian of mathematics.  Can you tell me a little about your background so that I can understand better how to view your response?

Comment: I used to be a professional group theorist for more than ten years ...

Comment: Many thanks for your useful answer.